# Problem with Hypergeometric Function

Tags: special-functions

I am working on the following code,

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
Off[General::munfl];
Off[General::spell];
Off[General::spell1];
Γ = 50;
Gμ = 10^-10;
α = 0.3688566917981026`;
 ξr = 0.271108;
 c = 0.23;
  a0 = 1;
 Ω0mat = 0.3153;
 Ω0rad = 9.21871*10^-5;
 h = 0.6736;
 H0 = ((100*10^3*h)/(3.08568*10^22))(*1 MPc=3.086*10^22*);
tpl = 5.39*10^-44(*sec*);
aeq = a0 Ω0rad/Ω0mat;
νr = 0.662062;
 c = 0.23;
 \[ScriptCapitalG] = 1;
 Ar = ℱ *c/Sqrt[2] νr/ξr^3;
 ℱ = 0.1;
ai = (Sqrt[2] a0 Sqrt[H0] Sqrt[tpl] Ω0rad^(1/4))/Gμ;
Cr = (c*νr)/(Sqrt[2]*α*ξr^4) (α*ξr + Γ*Gμ)^(3/2);
ϵr = (α*ξr)/(Γ*Gμ);
\[ScriptCapitalA]rr = (128 π)/9 ℱ*Cr*\[ScriptCapitalG]*h^2*Ω0rad (Gμ/Γ)^(1/2);
 S1rr[x_] = x^(3/2)/(1 + x)^(3/2);
 xerr = f/ferr;
 ferr = a0/aeq h0r;
 h0r = (4*H0r)/(Γ Gμ);
 H0r = H0*Sqrt[\[ScriptCapitalG]*Ω0rad];
 xsrr = If[ϵr^-1 > ϕ2[xir, ϵr], ϵr^-1, ϕ2[xir, ϵr]];
 xsrr1 = ϕ2[xir, ϵr];
 xir = f/fir;
 fir = a0/ai*h0r;
 q = 4/3;
 ϕ2[x_, ϵ_] = Sqrt[1/4 + (1 + ϵ) x^2] - 1/2;
 h2Ωrr1[f_] = \[ScriptCapitalA]rr/Zeta[q] Sum[j^-q (S1rr[xerr/j] - 
 S1rr[xsrr/j]), {j, 1, 1}];
 h2Ωrr2[f_?NumericQ] := \[ScriptCapitalA]rr/Zeta[q] NIntegrate[j^-q (S1rr[xerr/j] - S1rr[xsrr/j]), {j, 2, ∞}];
 h2Ωrr[f_] = 
   h2Ωrr1[f] + h2Ωrr2[f];
    S1rrsumj[f_] = 1/(1 + 2 q) 2^(3/2 - q) (1/((1/xerr)^(3/2) (2 + xerr)) (2 (1 + q) 
      Hypergeometric2F1[-(1/2), 1/2 + q,3/2 + q, -(xerr/2)] - (1 + q (2 + xerr)) 
       Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, 1/2 + q, 3/2 + q, -(xerr/2)]) + 1/((1/xsrr)^(3/2) (2 +xsrr)) (-2 (1 + q) Hypergeometric2F1[-(1/2), 1/2 + q, 
      3/2 + q, -(xsrr/2)] + (1 + q (2 + xsrr)) Hypergeometric2F1[
      1/2, 1/2 + q, 3/2 + q, -(xsrr/2)]));
     h2Ωrrsumtot[f_] = \[ScriptCapitalA]rr/
      Zeta[q] (1^-q (S1rr[xerr/1] - S1rr[xsrr/1]) + S1rrsumj[f]);
  h2RadExp[f_] = (
   h^2 128 Ar π Sqrt[
    Gμ/Γ] (Gμ Γ + α \
   ξr)^(
    3/2) ((a f Gμ Γ)/(
     a f Gμ Γ + 4 H0 Sqrt[Ω0rad]))^(
     3/2) Ω0rad)/(9 α ξr);
```

When I plot the result,

```
  LogLogPlot[{h2Ωrr[f], h2Ωrrsumtot[f]}, {f,
    10^-26, 10^21}, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {HoldForm[f[Hz]], 
   HoldForm[h^2 Subscript[Ω, GW]], 
   HoldForm[Gμ = "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-10\)]\)"]}, 
    PlotRange -> {{10^-19, 10^21}, {1*10^-25, 5*10^-6}}, 
  FrameStyle -> Directive[Black], 
  PlotStyle -> {{Darker[Green]}, {Red}, {Gray, Dashed}, {Gray, 
    Dashed}, {Purple}}, ImageSize -> Large, FrameTicks -> Automatic]
```

I have the following output,
[image]

In my code `S1rrsumj[f_]` and `h2Ωrr2[f_?NumericQ]` are basically the same expressions. In one case I am performing the numerical integration and in another, I just integrate it from `2` to `∞` and I have an analytical expression in terms of Hypergeometric functions. Why the `S1rrsumj[f_]` term does not go to the higher values of `f` and give me the noise? Can anyone please explain the issue? Is it something related to the Hypergeometric function? Is there any alternative to it? Because I really need the analytical expression at the end.

Comment: Before asking a question try to workout a minimal example where the problem appears. I'm  sure your problem is trivial however I'm not going to read such an awful code.

Comment: Pasting in the first part of the code results in a syntax error:  `Syntax::bktmop: Expression "<<1>>)" has no opening "(".`  Please make sure your code can be copied and pasted without syntax errors.

Comment: I have edited the code, please check now.

Comment: `Rationalize[#, 0]&` all of your constants and add `WorkingPrecision -> 15` to the plot.

Comment: Is `5.39*10^-44(*sec*)` from real world (see [Second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second))?

Comment: @BobHanlon Your suggestion only help to remove the noise, it does not let the plot proceed to the higher values of `f``. I need consistency between the two results i.e., the one from analytical expression and the other from numerical integration.
@user64494 it is the Planck time so very early time, somewhere in the beginning of Universe.

Comment: Evaluate `{h2\[CapitalOmega]rr[f], h2\[CapitalOmega]rrsumtot[f]}` for values of `f` (e.g., 1.*^-9 and 1.*^11) and you will see that your functions are not evaluating successfully. You need to get that fixed before you worry about plotting.